# Recycler view Scroll Up and down issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I have use section header recycler view for gallery and I want select all options in to that gallery. Everything is working fine but when I scroll up all select check box automatically unchecked because my total selected counter is reduced and not match with array list size.

Please give me a solution how to fix this

Comment: You probably have a problem with view rebinding, but without code snippets it is hard to tell

Comment: Please add code of your data class/ model and your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code snippet I can't say for sure, but obviously when you scroll, recycler view will recycle the item and the state of your item will lost. In order to keep the state, you need to save them somewhere for further interaction. As an example you can use a `hashmap` to store the state:

```kotlin
// Declare a HashMap to store the checked state of items
val checkedItems: HashMap<Int, Boolean> = HashMap()
```

In your RecyclerView adapter, update the `onBindViewHolder` method to set the checked state of the checkboxes based on the `checkedItems` HashMap:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // Bind data to the view holder

    // Set the checked state of the checkbox based on the checkedItems HashMap
    val isChecked = checkedItems[position] ?: false
    holder.checkbox.isChecked = isChecked

    // Set an OnClickListener for the checkbox
    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener {
        val isChecked = holder.checkbox.isChecked
        checkedItems[position] = isChecked
    }
}
```

In your item view holder, define a checkbox view and any other necessary views:

```kotlin
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val checkbox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
    // Other views in the item layout
}
```

When initializing your RecyclerView, make sure to set the checked state of the checkboxes based on the `checkedItems` HashMap:

```kotlin
// Initialize or populate your RecyclerView
// ...

// Set the checked state of checkboxes
for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
    val isChecked = checkedItems[i] ?: false
    holder.checkbox.isChecked = isChecked
}
```